list comprehension on Spacy nlp pipe generator
I am trying to run a nlp.pipe() generator (for NER) on this test data using a loop and list comprehension instead of a nested loop.
When I run the list comprehension version, I get 2 entities versus 6 with the nested loop.
What am I doing wrong on my list comprehension?
test_data = ['\n66.\t  We are genuinely pleased to applaud the wisdom shown by the General Assembly in the election of its President','117.\t It is for me a source of great pleasure to extend to the President, on behalf of the Liberian delegation, sincere congratulations on his election to the presidency',"78.\t  It gives me great pleasure, Sir, to express my warmest congratulations on your election as President of the thirtieth session of the General Assembly"]

The List Comprehension version (I get 2 entities)
for doc in nlp.pipe(test_data, disable=["tok2vec", "tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer"]):
    entities_text_2 = [ent.text for ent in doc.ents]
    

The nested loop version (I get 6 entities)
entities_text_3 = []

for doc in nlp.pipe(test_data, disable=["tok2vec", "tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer"]):
    for test in doc.ents:
        entities_text_3.append(test.text)
        


You are overwriting the list comprehension result each time.  Declare a master list outside the loop and .extend it with each list comprehension result.

@snakecharmerb ah, duh! thanks

@snakecharmerb feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept!
